# Excel formula for extracting text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following within cell A1:

```
NEW ORLEANS (0-0) at GREEN BAY (0-0)
```

I would like a formula to place in cell B1 "NEW ORLEANS" and in C1 "GREEN BAY.

Comment: Does the text change or is it always as you gave?

Comment: @Linker3000:  The text will change.  Thanks

Comment: Ok, so can we say you want the text before the first ( in B1 and the text between 'at' and second ( in C1 ??

Comment: @Linker3000: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the first team:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1)-2)
```

To get the second team:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" at ",A1)+4,FIND("(",A1,FIND(")",A1))-FIND(" at ",A1)-5)
```

Comment: Worked Great no matter what the score stated is.  Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

So if you had that cell in A1, then this in B1:

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND("(", A1)-2)
```

And this in C1:

```
=MID(A1, FIND(")", A1) + 4, LEN(A1)-FIND(")", A1)-9)
```

Note that this is very dependent on the sample that you gave being representative of the layout of the text in the other cells. It is based on finding the Parenthesis in the string. Actually I just realized that it will probably break if the numerals in the second (0-0) go to double digits. To account for that you would have to look for the second set of parens to determine the length for the Mid() call. To be honest, if this were my problem to solve, then I think that I would just write a VBA macro using split.

So via VBA, I would do something like this. Add these two functions:

```
Function GetFirstTeam()
    Application.Volatile
    GetFirstTeam = Trim(Split(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1), "(")(0))
End Function

Function GetSecondTeam()
    Application.Volatile
    GetSecondTeam = Trim(Split(Split(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2), " at ")(1), "(")(0))
End Function
```

Then in B1:

```
=GetFirstTeam()
```

And in C1:

```
=GetSecondTeam()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  You are correct by stating the numbers might be a double digit.  I was really hoping to stay away from VBA.  Is there anyway to do that or is it getting too complicated?

Comment: if you change C1 to this, it works for double-digit as well as single- and multi-word teams (until the 2nd team goes 10-10, anyway): =MID(A1, FIND("at", A1) + 2, LEN(A1)-FIND(")", A1)-9)

Comment: @StevenV : Thanks, it worked great.  It looks like there's a space before the second team in C1.  Is there a way to remove it with the formula you stated?  =MID(A1, FIND("at", A1) + 2, LEN(A1)-FIND(")", A1)-9)

Comment: If you are going to do it via formula and acomodate any score then you would just need to find the location of "at" for the start of the mid, Then find the location of the second "(" and the difference of those two values minus 4 would be the length of the mid. I'm just too lazy to put that into a formula.

Comment: getting closer, though I still have some scenarios where it fails: =LEFT(MID(A1, FIND("at", A1) + 3, LEN(A1)-FIND(")", A1)), FIND("(", A1)-3)

Comment: Good stuff - this saved me typing it all out :-)

Comment: You should be aware that you need to include spaces around "at" in your FIND functions. Games with SeATtle will cause problems.

Comment: Ooh good point.